Snowflake `Table`s vs Snowflake `DataFrame`s in Snowpark
Two things I've come across while trying to learn Snowflake Snowpark is that they mention both Tables and DataFrames.
The docs say that you can load an existing table from Snowflake database after creating a session:
connection_parameters = {
    "account": credentials["account"],
    "user": credentials["username"],
    "password": credentials["password"],
}

new_session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
new_session.sql("USE DATABASE test_db;").collect()

my_table = new_session.table("my_table")

When I print the type of my_table, it says it is of type Table. But the docs refer to it as DataFrames.
But then, there is this confusing example in the API reference for the Table class:
df1 = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], schema=["a", "b"])
df1.write.save_as_table("my_table", mode="overwrite", table_type="temporary")

session.table("my_table").collect()

So, I have no idea which is which and why we need both if they are different things.

I'm not an expert in this area, but the purpose of Snowpark is mostly to allow users to leverage Spark-like code against Snowflake tables.  So, you can define a table as a dataframe and then run dataframe-like code against it.  If it appears that there are multiple ways to do these things, it's likely for compatibility purposes.

Class Table extends class DataFrame. It is unfortunate that the Snowflake documentation is not as clear in distinguishing between the two.
A DataFrame is a collection of Row objects with columns defined by a schema. There are multiple ways to instantiate a DataFrame including:

Reading a table in Snowflake (the case in which Table extends DataFrame)
Reading files from a stage
Specifying a sequence or range
Creating a new DataFrame by applying transformations to an exising DataFrame.

